# Why would a pod consume a lot of resource while the micro service is simple

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I noticed that there is my very simple micro service deployed in kubernetes that consumes a large amount of memory  in starting process .about 4G memory just starting .yet I wasn't able to know the reason.
Regardless of the micro service 's function but it's weird that it consumes a huge amount of memory just for starting.
How does that happens and how to solve this problem ?.
Thank you

Comment: You'd have to show us your dockerfile and tell us something about your app. But, if you're talking about Windows containers, despite what some people might try to tell you, docker is a linux technology and it is barely functional when using windows containers.

Comment: Hello , the docker file is too simple : FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8090
ADD /target/gestion-voyages-client-1.0.jar gestion-voyages-client.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","gestion-voyages-client.jar"] , nothing complicated and the it has nothing to do with the windows containers . for the application it only contain simple entities with some rest api CRUD , nothing simpler than this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Resource requests and Resource Limits issue on k8s side, [this link explains multiple ways to manage CPU & memory usage in a container](https://learnk8s.io/setting-cpu-memory-limits-requests) . One k8s native way to do all of that would be the VPA Vertical Pod Autoscaler you can set a min and max for CPU & Memory usage, this way your pod won't consume more than what you assign to it.